# how can I take form names from SQLServer automatically

Tags: c#

I want to add menu item from the database.

For example when I add a menu name into the database. It locates itself automatically.

Inside of the table, I have 3 columns.

```
ID, FormName, DisplayName.
```

How can I do it? 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Please show us your effort and get help from us to your specific problem.

Comment: ı have a dockpanel. ı have to add manually menu items, but ı have so many form...

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very clear what you mean, but: you can query the *schema* of tables either implicitly (`select * from SomeTable`, perhaps with a `where 1=0`, or there is a `SET` option to disable row returns) - then look at the `IDataReader` or `DataTable` or however else you're querying it to understand the layout; or perhaps better: by querying the meta-tables - `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` etc. Once you know the column names and types, you can write a UI that does moderately suitable things based on that. If you need additional configuration, the "extended properties" feature of SQL Server allows you to store additional metadata against tables, columns, etc as name/value string pairs - essentially like `[SomeAttribute(...)]` in C#; for example, the `MS_Description` key/value pair is used by many UI tools to hold the descriptive label of a database entity (table, column, etc) - much like `[Description("...")]`. Putting all that together allows things to be *barely tolerable* by putting basic controls up to match each column/field with names and captions, but: a UI based on the raw database schema is usually very unsatisfying, and for most real work you'll want a custom UI with suitable logic and design considerations for the operation you're actually doing at the time.

Comment: thanks for reply. . when ı add a form name to the sqlserver, ı want to see it on my project. ı will have an area for this.ı dont want to add items manually. ı want it make automatically.